# "-bash: fork: Cannot allocate memory" at every command I enter, I'm stuck

Tags: python, memory, io

I executed a python script that uses basically all the memory of my vps because it does I/O operations with files of huge dimensions. I executed this script as root.

I tried to do a `killall python3`
but still the same error.

```
-bash: fork: Cannot allocate memory
```

I tried `su`, the same.

I tried reboot, but since I am not root at the moment and I can't "su" , I can't reboot.

What can I do to "unlock" this situation?

Comment: Is it running as a child of your shell? If so, type `jobs -l` to see its pid. Then type `kill -9 -ThePidYouFound` to kill off that process group.

Comment: Your vps service may also have an option to migrate the running vm to an instance with more memory.

Answer (score 3):

As a last resort (Kills **ALL** process):

`kill -9 -1`

> Kill is a shell builtin for two reasons: it allows job IDs to be used
>       instead of process IDs, and allows processes to be killed if the limit
>       on processes that you can create is reached.

Comment: I use kill all the time, but passing neg 1 sounds like a BAAAAAAD Idea and would suggest never doing that.

Comment: It will only kill the processes of this user. It is a bad idea, unless, all other ideas are worse. @Fallenreaper